# Convolution of a function and Dirac delta - special case

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

[image]

Could anyone tell me where $f(n(a-b))$ came from? The thing is easy when there's $f(x)$ instead of $f(nx)$ - the result would be $f(a-b)$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting $g(x)=f(nx)$. Then your integral is $g(a-b)=f(n(a-b))$.